# FastAPI slows file download over time

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, fastapi

I've written a Flask app with a FastAPI backend driven by uvicorn and it serves both HTTP requests and also socket data (for server driven messages to all clients).

I'm using the `FileResponse` method to return the html.

If I start the server and head to the IP, then it loads reasonably quickly at around 2 seconds. A day or so later, this time has increased to around 15 seconds. As time goes on it becomes slower and slower until I decide to restart the server. Note that this is all running on the same network and it's all downloaded via ethernet - no Wi-Fi.

Inspecting what's happening, it appears as though it's taking ages to download a 1.6MB resource. But what I don't understand is why it becomes progressively slow over time. If there's a cached version of the page, then it remains quick.

I imagine it has something to do with the fact that the FileResponse class asynchronously streams a file as the response so after some time it may stream the javascript file in bits (which is what I see when I inspect). Does anyone know how to make the `FileResponse` just send the whole file in one go?

Comment: I think it's the FileResponse that's the issue. I've just changed over to the HTMLResponse option and it appears to be working, but it will take a day or so to see if it slows over time or not.

Comment: Nope. Switching to the HTMLResponse has not cleared the issue. It's definitely slow again. One thing to note is that you can actually watch the slow file sdownload by directly requesting the chunk.js file in question and watch it slowly get larger. Any help would be greatly appreciated.